# How to send a POST request via WebKit [PySide/PyQt]

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Using PySide, how to get the POST data from a form the webkit in python code?

Here is my simple code:

```
    import sys 
    from PySide.QtCore import * 
    from PySide.QtGui import QApplication 
    from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebView 

    html = """ 
    <html> 
    <body> 
        <form action="" method="post"><input name="test" /><input type="submit" value="submit"/></form>
    </body> 
    </html> 
    """ 


    if __name__ == '__main__': 
        app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
        view = QWebView() 
        frame = view.page().mainFrame() 
        view.setHtml(html) 
        view.show() 
        app.exec_()
```

I want to get the string[key=test] that I submited

Comment: How do you want to "get" the value? You can't do a "self" post request unless a server is there to handle the request. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

By binding your custom createRequest virtual function to the network manager, you can see the data being posted:

**NOTICE:** using *data.readAll()* will empty the sequential *QIODevice*, so a bit later webkit won't be able to access the data, and nothing will be posted. Using *data.peak(1024)*
 will have the same effect without losing the data, the only inconvenience is that you have to pass the data size you wish to read.

```
import sys 
from PySide.QtCore import * 
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication 
from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebView, QWebPage
from PySide.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager

html = ''' 
<html> 
<body> 
    <form action="http://www.google.com" method="post"><input type="text" name="test" /><input type="submit" value="submit"/></form>
</body> 
</html> 
''' 

class Browser(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.network_manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.network_manager.createRequest = self._create_request

        self.web_page = QWebPage()
        self.web_page.setNetworkAccessManager(self.network_manager)

        self.web_view = QWebView()
        self.web_view.setPage(self.web_page)

        self.html_data = None

    def _create_request(self, operation, request, data):
        # data contains all the post data that is being added to the request
        # so you can look into it here
        print data.readAll()
        reply = QNetworkAccessManager.createRequest(self.network_manager,
                                                    operation,
                                                    request,
                                                    data)
        return reply

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    browser = Browser() 
    frame = browser.web_page.mainFrame() 
    browser.web_view.setHtml(html) 
    browser.web_view.show() 
    app.exec_()
```